# DATEDIFF in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, datediff

I would like to used the `DATEDIFF` function like so in a MySQL query:

```
SELECT `ItemType`, 
       `DateOpen` AS StartDate, 
       IFNULL (`DateClosed`, CURDATE()) AS EndDate, 
       DATEDIFF(`EndDate`, `StartDate`) AS ItemLife
FROM `Items` 
WHERE `ProjectID`=11
ORDER BY `ItemType` ASC
```

The above query fails because of the `DATEDIFF` part. I tried the column names with and without the the back ticks with no difference. Is my syntax wrong or am I violating some some SQL language rule?

Taking the `DATEDIFF` part out makes the query run smoothly.

hope someone can help.

thanks

Comment: If I understand right you're trying to use `EndDate` within datediff that doesn't exist. You need to use your function of the row above within datediff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use aliases you have defined in same query's `select` and `where` section 
(but you can in in `group by`, `having`,`order by` and aliases defined in subqueries)

```
SELECT `ItemType`, 
       `DateOpen` AS StartDate, 
       IFNULL (`DateClosed`, CURDATE()) AS EndDate, 
       DATEDIFF(IFNULL (`DateClosed`, CURDATE()), `DateOpen`) AS ItemLife
FROM `Items` 
WHERE `ProjectID`=11
ORDER BY `ItemType` ASC
```

or

```
SELECT t.*,
       DATEDIFF(`EndDate`, `StartDate`) AS ItemLife
FROM (
    SELECT `ItemType`, 
           `DateOpen` AS StartDate, 
           IFNULL (`DateClosed`, CURDATE()) AS EndDate
    FROM `Items` 
    WHERE `ProjectID`=11
    ORDER BY `ItemType` ASC
) t
```

Comment: Hey Imre, thanks for the detailed response. I'll be using the first format. cheers!